# The Axiom Schema of Comprehension and sets of random, unrelated objects

Tags: set-theory

I'm wrapping up an extended self study of set theory to do a deep dive into topology and would like to lock down a conceptual matter regarding the naive set theory (NST) axiom schema of comprehension (and I suppose the axiom schema of separation of ZFC). According to Wikipedia,

> ...each of these axioms states that a certain set exists, and defines that set by giving a predicate for its members to satisfy

I understand one MAY define a set using predicate notation ($A=\{X:P(X)\}$ is perfectly intuitive). But this statement and similar language in other books I have read seem to suggest that all sets have a corresponding predicate which define their elements. This seems contrary to the notion that a set can contain anything, that the elements don't have to be related in some way (although they often are). For example, I assume that the following collection of unrelated real and abstract objects is a perfectly legitimate set (though not a terribly useful one).

$$
A=\{quark,wisdom,Andromeda Galaxy,\{748\},Lichtenstein's GDP\}
$$

Is it possible that all these axioms are saying is that I can construct a trivial predicate to specify my set?

$$
P(X)=(X=quark)\vee (X=wisdom)\vee (X=Andromeda Galaxy)\vee (X=\{748\})\vee(X=Lichtenstein's GDP)
$$

My struggle reconciling the apparent underpinning of these axioms with sets with apparently random elements also appears in trying to understand fully axiomatic constructions where "everything is a set" and the Von Neumann universe approach where all sets are simply collection of nestings of the empty set which can model any useful mathematical set such as the natural numbers.

$$
0=\emptyset;1=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\};...n=\{\emptyset,\{n-1\}...
$$
But how does one model a set of completely random objects as above, using such a construction of nested empty sets? Feels like there is more to it and that I am missing a key conceptual point. Thanks.

Comment: I think ZFC set theory does not model random objects, but rather mathematical structures. You could call some set "quark" if you wish, but it won't become the real thing; on the other hand if you want to model how quarks interact, you probably could do so in set theory and probably then you would find a set for which name "quark" would be justified.

Comment: Additionally, if you have finitely many sets $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$, even if their constructions aren't clearly related, you can construct the set $\{a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ by pairing and union. This even applies to sets which have *no* definition, which exist depending on your response to the [math-tea argument](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597) - "there must be some set with no definition since there are uncountably many sets, but only countably many definitions that can be written with finite length".

Comment: Thanks @Esgeriath. I accept the notion that sets are abstractions and not the real thing, but we certainly can use sets and set theory to model real things (e.g. familial relationships). Also, doesn't the question hold even for things we would call purely mathematical structures. One can certainly construct a set of random numbers with no obvious predicate formula binding them together, e.g. $\{1965, \pi,-9.67E-99\}$, right?

Comment: Thanks @C7X. The article you cite is quite a bit over my head but I understand the question being tacked and your summary of it. I understand/accept that ZFC offers the tools to construct set of apparently unrelated objects (sets). What I am stuck on is the suggestion in the line I quote that for a set to exist there has to be a predicate formula that specifies its elements. Wondering if I am misreading that line or if the predicate formula can simply be the trivial one - a conjunction of the elements memberships.